# How to graph series in Desmos $f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{x}nb-f_{1}\left(f\left(x-1\right)\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, desmos

$$f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{x}nb-f_{1}\left(f\left(n-1\right)\right)$$

$$b=2$$

$$f_1(x)=x^2$$

$$f(1)=b$$

How can I define this whole series in Desmos?

Comment: Would you be able to define $f(x)$ first? Desmos only supports implicit equations of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: In this case, only f(1) is defined, and then larger(Integer) values would be built off of that